# CachetHQ Incident API

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I have a basic CachetHQ status page set up, and have gone through the entire configuration process.  I have my user, who has an API key.

I have been able to get the creation of an incident working through the API (authenticating and posting to http://domain.com/api/v1/incidents) however, when I try to do the PUT request with a specific incident in mind, it fails giving me a "403 - Forbidden".  Is there something special which I need to do in order to support this?

The cURL request looks like this:

```
curl -X PUT -H "X-Cachet-Token: API-KEY-HERE" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 6e023e6d-329a-9b00-b027-33b259264680" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "name=Incident #1 - Foo" -F "component_id=3" -F "status=1" "http://status.icepets.com/api/v1/incidents/4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my previous experiences on the server, I have figured out the issue.  The server was not accepting all of the different verbs (i.e. PUT/DELETE).

I have switched my script to use Laravel's spoofed method, and it worked like a charm.